# Passing parameters in Google News app URL scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, google-news

I want to integrate the Google News app with another iOS customized app. I've found the URL scheme for Google News (`googlenews://`) and it opens the app. Now I am trying to pass a parameter in order to automatically search news for it. I've used the following URLs with no success.

- `googlenews://news.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow`
- `googlenews://q=stackoverflow`
- `googlenews://?q=stackoverflow`

Looks simple but it doesn't work. How to do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a parameter search to Google News, you can try the following:

```
https://news.google.com/news/section?cf=all&hl=us&ned=en_us&q=<YOUR_SEARCH_TERM>
```

Where `<YOUR_SEARCH_TERM>` is the parameter you want search.